# How t find z (unknown) in Runge-Kutta question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm trying to solve the below question

> solve $\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{1}{x+y}$ for $x=0.5$ to $z$ using R-K (order $4$) with $x_0=0$, $y_0=1$ (take $h=0.5$).

Please help me and tell me how to calculate $z$. And how many $x$ will be here and what will be their values?

Comment: This is miss-printing in a book, this is not z but 2.